# Orthogonal projection onto a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Find the minimal distance from the point
$P = \begin{bmatrix}\\
-8 \\
14 \\
8
\end{bmatrix}$ to the plane $V$ of $\mathcal{R}^3$ spanned by 
$\begin{bmatrix}\\
1 \\
2 \\
-2
\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$\begin{bmatrix}\\
6 \\
-5 \\
-2
\end{bmatrix}$.

How would I compute this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  See the picture below and don't forget to normalize the normal.  What are the coordinates of the closest point?

[image]